# How Connect Quickbooks online essential account to our web hosted website for any online users?

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Is there any way Or API available in PHP which automatically enter any customer records with billing and shipping information and products information which product they buy from our site and what amount they pay for that products added into our quick book online essential account ?

we have our quick book online essential account, but now I have to integrate that account with our hosted application and automatically insert, update that delete that customer's records and invoices into our quick book essential account ?

We have cloths products for sell in our website.which have QBMS and PAYPAL for payment gateway.

Please let me know is there any possibility like this ?

I have read developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi but not getting too much idea.

Please note I want to add,edit delete customer's records and invoice receipt, which will be fill up in our website, our website's customer didn't have any quick book account, they will pay by credit cards OR pay pal account. So is there any way to adding all these information in quick book online data. there is api that I already read that document but there is no code samples available that will connect our website data to our quick book online account. So is there any way OR it is not possible to connect any online users to our quick book account ?

From where I have to start for integrating quick book online essential and our web site? Please let me know.

Thank You

Yes Nimisha,
I am using same PHP dev kit from keith palmer.
I am sucessfully able to create QBOE and QBMS applications in "PRODUCTION" mode.
But I am stuck in QBXML code. It will respond me blank. and I am not able to PUSH data from my website to quick book online essential account.
Below is my code,

```
<?qbxml version="6.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <SignonMsgsRq>
        <SignonDesktopRq>
       <ClientDateTime>2013-10-04T12:49:04</ClientDateTime>
            <ApplicationLogin>********************</ApplicationLogin>
            <ConnectionTicket>********************</ConnectionTicket> 
            <Language>English</Language>
            <AppID>************</AppID>
            <AppVer>1</AppVer>
        </SignonDesktopRq>
    </SignonMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 04 Oct 2013 06:13:21 GMT Server: Apache/1.3.41 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.8.31 OpenSSL/0.9.8r ApacheJServ/1.1.2
Content-Type: text/plain Transfer-Encoding: chunked

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE QBXML PUBLIC "-//INTUIT//DTD QBXML QBO 6.0//EN" "http://apps.quickbooks.com/dtds/qbxmlops60.dtd">
 <QBXML>
    <SignonMsgsRs>
    <SignonDesktopRs statusCode="2000" statusMessage="Application agent not found **************" statusSeverity="ERROR">
    <ServerDateTime>2013-10-04T06:13:47</ServerDateTime>
    </SignonDesktopRs></SignonMsgsRs>
 </QBXML>
```

Please provide me some help for push data to quickbook online essential account.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a custom integration using SDK with QBO/QBD Apis, then it is not supported. You cannot automatically pass data from you site to QBO account as manual intervention is a must for the QBO/QBD Apis as you get the access to your company file only after the 3-legged OAUTH flow. To add to that, we currently have sample apps available only in .net and java. We are soon going to release a PHP one too.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/sample_code

If however, you see a possibility that users can login and complete the OAUTH flow, then please check this out-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started

For custom integration, you might want to look at the QBXML- 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb

Comment: Thanks nimisha,

But I have one php library from consolibyte and they told me that this is possible to push data to QuickBooks Online via an API. 
Please see this URL,
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0260_pos/0050_documentation/sample_code
there is availabiliy of all XML codes for adding products,sales receipt ,customers.
So is it possible with these XML codes ?

Comment: As I mentioned, it is possible via QBXML(POS)-https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits   You can use Consolibyte's PHP library too.